# NHL forfeit shutouts

Tags: rules, statistics, ice-hockey, nhl

In the NHL, if a game is forfeited the loser gets score 0 and the winner gets 1 or higher if the game was forfeited after it started already and the winner scored more than 1 goal. All personal stats for players from both teams are recorded if some portion of the game was played.

But how is it with shutouts?

There are different scenarios, supposing that Team A is the forfeit team and 1 goalkeeper from each team plays the whole match.

1. score at the end was Team A 0:0 Team B
2. score at the end was Team A 2:2 Team B

and

- game ended after 5 minutes
- game ended at time 59:50
- (only for option 1) game ended after overtime and a shootout was not held because the forfeit occurred after overtime

In all scenarios, when will each team and/or each goalkeeper be credited with a shutout?

Answer (score 2):

No shutout would be awarded, because none had been earned.

Per [NHL rules, 66, Foreit of Game](https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/assets/binary/319997074/binary-file/file.pdf):

> If the game is declared forfeited prior to its having commenced, the score shall be recorded as 1-0 and no player shall be credited with any personal statistics.
>
> If the game was in progress at the time it is declared forfeited, the score shall be recorded as zero for the loser and 1, or such greater number of goals that had been scored by it, for the winner; however, the players on both Clubs shall be credited with all personal statistics earned up to the time the forfeit was declared.

A shutout is earned when the game is *completed*, but in a forfeited game that does not occur.

Comment: And what about game being forfeited after overtime which ended 0:0?

Comment: If the game didn’t end then the shutout isn’t awarded.

Comment: Thanks. However goalies could be awarded a win/loss even in incomplete game: "If the winning team by forfeit is ahead at
the time of forfeit, enter as winning and losing goaltenders the
players who would have qualified if the game had been a completed game at the time of forfeit." (http://fs.ncaa.org/Docs/stats/Stats_Manuals/IceHockey/2012EZ.pdf)
Why not a shutout then?
Have you found any reference to it?